# DataTable update to 1.11 destroy returning error

Tags: javascript, datatables

My app is running fine on version 1.10.24 and 1.10.25.

Recently I am trying to update packages and moved to 1.11.3 and I am starting to get error.

My code is fairly simple. But logic; is that I have a `Start Process` button, when that is pressed certain data is processed on server and response comes via web-socket which is added to table using `table.add()`, this works fine first time. But user can press the button again to reprocess the data on server. For this, I am clearing the table.

for

```js
$('#testGrid').DataTable().destroy();
```

I am getting following error

```
dataTables.colResize.js:262 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dt')
    at ColResize._fnStateSave (dataTables.colResize.js:262)
    at jQuery.fn.init.<anonymous> (dataTables.colResize.js:249)
    at jquery.dataTables.js:6754
    at Function.map (jquery.js:467)
    at _fnCallbackFire (jquery.dataTables.js:6753)
    at _fnSaveState (jquery.dataTables.js:6405)
    at _Api.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:8815)
    at _Api.iterator (jquery.dataTables.js:7145)
    at _Api.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:8804)
    at _Api.visible (jquery.dataTables.js:7312)
```

for

```js
let testGrid = $('#testGrid').DataTable();
testGrid.clear().draw();
```

There is no error, and after pressing process button, an error is thrown as soon I try to add data

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_aData')
    at _Api.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:8278)
    at _Api.data (jquery.dataTables.js:7312)
    at results-timeline-grid.js:254
    at arrayEach (_arrayEach.js:16)
    at Function.forEach (forEach.js:43)
    at Class.updateDataSource (results-timeline-grid.js:235)
    at Class.onDataUpdated (data-grid.js:31)
    at sendEvent (index.js:219)
    at Class.trigger (evented.js:113)
    at Class.publish (event-bus.js:11)
```

As stated before, my code is working fine on 1.10.24, 1.10.25

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply, focus was switched to something else. Any how, today I tried to work on this, and figured that `jquery.dataTables.colResize.js` plugin was old. So updated all my plugins and it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using other plugins as well, which were not updated. After updating those plugins it is resolved